# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type JObject

Tags: c#

this is the first time that I come here to try to solve a problem, I've been studying C# for 4 weeks now, so I'm not an expert as you can imagine, so I've been coding since yesterday and I haven't been able to solve an error that keeps appearing no matter what I do "***Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type JObject***" I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
private static string GetTorrentUrl(string query)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string json = client.DownloadString(new Uri("https://yts.mx/ajax/search?query=" + query));

    Console.WriteLine(json);

    JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);
    if (result["status"].ToString == "ok")
    {
        JArray data = (JArray)result["data"];
        Console.WriteLine(data[0]["title"].ToString());

    }
    return "something";
}
```

I just try it and to it works but the Visual Studio keeps telling me that there's an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIJOg.jpg).

Comment: Which libraries are you using? Newtonson.Json and System.Net? If so, try to clean your solution.

Comment: Try `result.GetValue("staus")` (even though the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) seem to suggest that this indexr form is supported. Are you using the correct version and the correct classes?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are trying to get the properties like `["status"]` even though you do not know (Or compiler don't know) what that is.
C# is strongly typed so the compiler will detect and flag these errors at compilation time. 
If you look at the documentation for `JObject` you will see that it implements the interface: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, JToken>>`:

> public class JObject : JContainer, IDictionary<string, JToken>,
> ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>,
> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>,    IEnumerable,
> INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor, INotifyPropertyChanging
> Read more at - [Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

That means you can iterate the list simply by using a loop:

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
   if(item.Key == "status" && item.Value.ToString() == "ok")
     // logic here
}
```

It should also be possible to do it with Linq like this but haven't tested the code:

```
private static string GetTorrentUrl(string query)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string json = client.DownloadString(new Uri("https://yts.mx/ajax/search?query=" + query));

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    
    JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);
    var status = result.Where(x => x.Key == "status").First().Value;
    if(status == "ok")
    {
        JArray data = result.Where(x => x.Key == "data").First().Value;
        Console.WriteLine(data[0]["title"].ToString());

    }

    return "something";
}
```